# What is the command to switch to normal user?

Tags: command-line, su

I am trying to use the `su`/`sudo` command to switch to a regular user. It asks me for a password and I enter the admin password then it says `su: Authentication failure`:

```
walter@walter-VirtualBox:~/testdir$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
walter@walter-VirtualBox:~/testdir$
```

How can I switch to my regular user? What is the problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To enter type `sudo -i`.

To exit from super user mode type `exit`.

Answer (score 12):

You can switch to a different regular user by using the command su.

Example:
`su John`
Then put in the password for John and you'll be switched to the user 'John' in the terminal.